# Prove the series $\large \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \sin (ni)}{3^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove the series $\large \Sigma_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \sin (ni)}{3^n}$ converges. $i$ refers to $\sqrt{-1}$.

I tried proving using the Drichlet test without much success. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: try writing $\sin(ni)$ as a sum of exponentials...

Comment: Indeed.  To make A.P.'s hint more explicit, you should know that $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ by definition.

Comment: What English are you talking, that "assistance" is for the lazy, while "help" is not? As with many things in English, "help" is the Germanic root word, while "assistance" is the Latin root word, and thus sounds more formal. @Pedro

Comment: @Pedro A lot of English speakers, when trying to be polite or formal, default to the Latin-rooted English words, due to the role that Latin and French played in English society, legally (Latin,) religiously (Latin,) and in the aristocracy (French.)

Comment: It's not a conscious thing, but a relic that we subconsciously learn, and, today, perhaps, still used as a signifier of class and status in subtle ways. (Kids in high school who want to sound smart tend to start using the longer  Latin-rooted words.) In grad school, it was suggested that, when writing article,  we should prefer Latin-rooted words,  for easier readability by most Europeans. Germans have way more Latin words than Italians have Germanic words. @Pedro

Comment: Use the Weierstrass test. Not only does it converge, it even converges absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$. So what is $\sin{in}$? You'll need that $e<3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<1$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n\,z^n =\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\tag{1} $$
it follows that:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{in\sinh n}{3^n}=\frac{i}{2}\left(\sum_{n\geq 1}n\left(\frac{e}{3}\right)^n+\sum_{n\geq 1}n\left(\frac{1}{3e}\right)^n\right)=\color{red}{\frac{12i e(e^2-1)}{(e-3)^2(3e-1)^2}}.\tag{2}$$